# initialize(), registeroneofftask(), and executetask() is not founded

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

everything correct but its not working

[image]

I update my full flutter app and dart

workmanager is already in "dependencies". Will try to update the constraint.
Resolving dependencies... '

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `Workmanager.executeTask`, you're expecting that there is a [static method](https://dart.dev/language/classes#static-methods) called `executeTask` from the `Workmanager` class. The package author decided not, so you have to construct the `Workmanager` class by using its [unnamed constructor](https://dart.dev/language/constructors) (`Workmanager()`). Therefore, in order to call those methods you have to do it like this:

```dart
Workmanager().executeTask((task, inputData) {
  // ...
});
```

---

If you're unsure about how to use certain methods from the [workmanager](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager) package, you can see the [examples](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager#how-to-use-the-package) from the readme and copy the code from there.